# How to make a multi-join query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm new to SQL, and find I don't quite understand which joins to use when. Sub-queries also seem confusing. I have the following tables set up, and I'm trying to get a specific outcome:

```
`+--------------------------+   +---------------+  +---------------+  +---------------+`
`|          Table_A         |   |   Table_B     |  |   Table_C     |  |   Table_D     |`
`+--------------------------+   +---------------+  +---------------+  +---------------+`
`| id | f2 | f3 | f4 | d_id |   | a_id  | c_id  |  |  id  |   fc   |  |  id  |   fs   |`
`+--------------------------+   +---------------+  +---------------+  +---------------+`
```

And this is what I'm trying to get:

```
`+----------------------------------+`
`| a.f2 | a.f3 | a.f4 | d.fs | c.fc |`
`+----------------------------------+`
```

I've found that I can get the first four columns with the following query:

```
Select t1.f2, t1.f3, t1.f4, t2.fs
    From Table_A AS t1 INNER JOIN Table_D AS t2
    ON t1.d_id = t2.id;
```

How can I get from A.id to C.fc? I can't figure out how to get the fifth column, let alone in conjunction with the previous query. This is about as far as I got with the final column:

```
Select t1.flow_control
    FROM Table_D AS t1 INNER JOIN policy t2
    ON t1.id = t2.c_id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Select t1.f2, t1.f3, t1.f4, t2.fs, t3.fc
    From Table_A AS t1
    INNER JOIN Table_D AS t2 ON t1.d_id = t2.id
    INNER JOIN Table_B AS jointable ON t1.id = jointable.a_id
    INNER JOIN Table_C AS t3 ON jointable.c_id = t3.id;
```

The first join is the one you originally had.  The second one is for the 'linking table', which represents a HABTM relationship between Table_A and Table_C. Once you've joined with that, you do a third join 'connecting' it to Table C so you can get that 'fc' field.  So essentially the first join is just for Table_D, and the two other JOINs get you to that last field.

You can have multiple JOINs in a single statement that link to completely different tables if that's what you need... it's just like connecting the dots / following the relationships :)

Comment: Also, note that with `INNER JOIN`, you will only get results where Table_A has related data in other tables. So if Table_A had two records and only one associated record in Table_D, your query wouldn't return that second record with no assoc data. If you needed to return all records from Table_A, including those with *no associated data* in other tables, you would want to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: Awesome! This works perfectly, and the additional explanation on joins was just what I was looking for. Thank you much.